# How to find last row of a column starting from a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
  lastrow = Sheets("User Interface").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB19").End(xlUp).row
```

I'm trying to find the last used row of a column starting at a specific cell, AB19. But there is an error. I'm still new to VBA so help is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't quite find the answer i'm looking for. what i'm trying to do is to find the last row of the column but starting at  a specific cell like column AB at row 19,cell  AB19 and count to the last used row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second factor of Cells is column, so you just put column reference there, i.e. "AB" instead of "AB19":

```
  lastrow = Sheets("User Interface").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).row
```

I did try and this worked.

Comment: @hyerii you are close to it, just fix the factor to right reference syntax.